# colcon build --symlink-install: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: ros2, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to install ROS 2 on my ubuntu 18.04 laptop.

However, after entering `colcon build --symlink-install`. I am met with this error,

```
Starting >>> test_launch_ros
--- stderr: test_launch_ros                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/executor/__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/__init__.py", line 92, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/task/ament_python/build.py", line 55, in build
    setup_py_data.get('data_files', []))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/python/__init__.py", line 34, in get_data_files_mapping
    for data_file in data_files:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
---
Failed   <<< test_launch_ros    [ Exited with code 1 ]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server         
Aborted  <<< test_communication                           
Aborted  <<< message_filters                             
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition         
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client       
Aborted  <<< rosbag2                                     
Aborted  <<< quality_of_service_demo_cpp                  
Aborted  <<< intra_process_demo                           
Aborted  <<< demo_nodes_cpp                               
Aborted  <<< test_quality_of_service                      
Aborted  <<< turtlesim
```

And

```
Summary: 220 packages finished [2min 23s]
  1 package failed: test_launch_ros
  11 packages aborted: demo_nodes_cpp examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition intra_process_demo message_filters quality_of_service_demo_cpp rosbag2 test_communication test_quality_of_service turtlesim
  1 package had stderr output: test_launch_ros
  39 packages not processed
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Please advise, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346226/colcon-build---symlink-install:-typeerror:-%27nonetype%27-object-is-not-iterable/) by [AHJL001](https://answers.ros.org/users/51756/ahjl001/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on this error, I'm guessing you're trying to build ROS 2 Dashing from source (despite the question being tagged `melodic`). Note that if you build the last distro: ROS Eloquent, you won't face the issue.

Can you confirm the version of `colcon-ros` you are using (you can run `colcon version-check`) ? How did you install colcon ?

It seems that some versions of colcon-ros had a bug in that regard that has been [recently fixed](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/pull/99).
To get the fix you need to be using `colcon-ros` 0.3.17, that is currently only available from pip, the deb version hasn't hit the main repository yet.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHJL001](https://answers.ros.org/users/51756/ahjl001/) on 2020-03-09**:
This was it! Merci beaucoup!

**Comment by [komkrit](https://answers.ros.org/users/52226/komkrit/) on 2020-03-09**:
$ colcon version-check
colcon-ros 0.3.16: newer version available (0.3.17)

How can i upgrade colcon-ros fot 0.3.16 --> 0.3.17

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-03-10**:
currently you either need to install it via pip:

```
pip3 install colcon-common-extensions
```

or to install the package from the testing repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2-testing/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-testing.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade python3-colcon-ros
```

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-03-10**:
You shouldn't install Python packages via `pip` if there are Debian packages for it. The Debian package should be in the `main` repo by now - so there shouldn't be a need to switch to the `testing` repo.

**Comment by [komkrit](https://answers.ros.org/users/52226/komkrit/) on 2020-03-11**:
Thank you so much merduedas...  _/|_